# Extracting photos from FB-graph with Meteor

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, meteor, handlebars.js, fb-graph

I'm trying to display photos from the NPM FB-Graph (https://npmjs.org/package/fbgraph) package by following this example (http://www.andrehonsberg.com/article/facebook-graph-api-meteor-js). I've managed to connect the API and render data, however I'm having trouble extracting the EJSON data into my picture template.

First off, let me show you the code I'm working with. Here is my client code:

```
  function Facebook(accessToken) {
    this.fb = Meteor.require('fbgraph');
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
    this.fb.setAccessToken(this.accessToken);
    this.options = {
        timeout: 3000,
        pool: {maxSockets: Infinity},
        headers: {connection: "keep-alive"}
    }
    this.fb.setOptions(this.options);
}

Facebook.prototype.query = function(query, method) {
    var self = this;
    var method = (typeof method === 'undefined') ? 'get' : method;
    var data = Meteor.sync(function(done) {
        self.fb[method](query, function(err, res) {
            done(null, res);
        });
    });
    return data.result;
}

Facebook.prototype.getUserData = function() {
    return this.query('me');
}
Facebook.prototype.getPhotos = function() {
    return this.query('/me/photos?fields=picture');
}

Meteor.methods({
    getUserData: function() {
        var fb = new Facebook(Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken);
        var data = fb.getPhotos();
        return data;
     }
});

Meteor.methods({
    getPhotos: function() {   
    var fb = new Facebook(Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken);
    var photos = fb.getPhotos;
    return photos;
}
});
```

Here is my client code:

```
Template.fbgraph.events({
    'click #btn-user-data': function(e) {
        Meteor.call('getUserData', function(err, data) {
            $('#result').text(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4));            
         });
    }
});

var fbPhotos = [];

Template.fbgraph.events({
    fbPhotos : function(e) {
        Meteor.call('getUserData', function(err, data) {
            $('input[name=fbPhotos]').text(EJSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4));            
         });
    }
});

Template.facebookphoto.helpers({ 
  pictures: fbPhotos
});
```

And here are my templates:

```
<template name="fbgraph">
    <div id="main" class="row-fluid">
      {{> facebookphoto}}
    </div>

    <button class="btn" id="btn-user-data">Get User Data</button>
    <div class="well">
        <pre id="result"></pre>
    </div>
</template>


<template name="facebookphoto">
  <div class="photos">
    {{#each pictures}}
      {{> photoItem}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="photoItem">
  <div class="photo">
    <div class="photo-content">
      <img class="img-rounded" src="{{picture}}">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Right now, I'm testing the data with the `id="results"` tag and the Facebook API returns data as below.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "picture": "https://photo.jpg",
            "id": "1234",
            "created_time": "2013-01-01T00:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
            "picture": "https://photo.jpg",
            "id": "12345",
            "created_time": "2013-01-01T00:00:00+0000"
        }
}
```

However I'm having difficulty pulling each of the pictures out of the EJSON and render them in templates. What I'd like to do is to display each picture in the {{picture}} template. I believe the problem with the code is somewhere in the client, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like in your client code you have

```
Template.fbgraph.events({ ... })
```

defined twice. Did you mean to write:

```
Template.fbgraph.helpers({
    fbPhotos : function(e) {
        Meteor.call('getUserData', function(err, data) {
            $('input[name=fbPhotos]').text(EJSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4));            
         });
    }
});
```

A simpler way to do it might just be to call the `getUserData` method in your `facebookphoto` template itself, thus:

```
Template.facebookphoto.helpers({
        pictures : function(e) {
            Meteor.call('getUserData', function(err, data) {
                $('input[name=fbPhotos]').text(EJSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4));            
             });
        }
});
```

Comment: Awesome, this helps. However I'm still having a bit of trouble rendering the pictures template. I modified what you provided to the code below. The photo renders in the console, however it doesn't hold for `pictures`. I'm sure there is an easy Meteor trick for this. Thoughts? `Template.facebookphoto.helpers({
        pictures: Meteor.call('getUserData', function(err, data) {
                var photo = data.data[0];   
                console.log(photo); 
                return photo;
             })     
});`

Comment: I'm a little confused on what your problem is. When the page renders, does it show the image tag `<img class="img-rounded" src="{{picture}}">` ? If so, what is the `src` of the img?

Comment: I'm bit confused on what my question is too :) If I hardcode picture in the client it will render to the template `{{picture}}` and I was able to render the data from FB, however I'm not able to connect the two. I looks like the issue is from not properly setting up collections--Your post helped push me to that conclusion. As of now I'm working on inserting data into MongoDB from FB for a new collection. I just opened another question regarding that, which I'm having trouble. Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733394/insert-data-to-meteor-from-facebook-api). Thanks!

Comment: Cool, I'm glad progress is being made. Good luck!