# Insert data to Meteor from Facebook API

Tags: json, mongodb, facebook-graph-api, meteor

I'm following the example given [here](http://www.andrehonsberg.com/article/facebook-graph-api-meteor-js) on pulling data from FB Graph. So far I've managed to pull data from FB however I can't figure out how to insert it into MongoDB.

Right now the data from Facebook renders as follows:

`{"data": [
        {
            "picture": "https://photo.jpg",
            "id": "1234",
            "created_time": "2013-01-01T00:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
            "picture": "https://photo.jpg",
            "id": "12345",
            "created_time": "2013-01-01T00:00:00+0000"
        }]
}`

I created a collection call Photos and I've tried to insert the data with `Photos.inser(data)`. Here is my server code:

```
 function Facebook(accessToken) {
    this.fb = Meteor.require('fbgraph');
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
    this.fb.setAccessToken(this.accessToken);
    this.options = {
        timeout: 3000,
        pool: {maxSockets: Infinity},
        headers: {connection: "keep-alive"}
    }
    this.fb.setOptions(this.options);
}

Facebook.prototype.query = function(query, method) {
    var self = this;
    var method = (typeof method === 'undefined') ? 'get' : method;
    var data = Meteor.sync(function(done) {
        self.fb[method](query, function(err, res) {
            done(null, res);
        });
    });
    return data.result;
}

Facebook.prototype.getUserData = function() {
    return this.query('me');
}
Facebook.prototype.getPhotos = function() {
    return this.query('/me/photos?fields=picture');
}

Meteor.methods({
    getUserData: function() {
        var fb = new Facebook(Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken);
        var data = fb.getUserData();
        return data;
        _.forEach(data.data, function(photo) {
            Photos.insert(photo, function(err) { 
                if(err) console.error(err); 
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Here is my collections code:

```
Photos = new Meteor.Collection('picture');
```

Right now, nothing is being inserted into MongoDB and I can't figure out why.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here or if there is a better way to approch this problem? 
 Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the autopublish package? If not, have you tried meteor mongo from the command line to see if the data is actually there but not published?

Comment: I have the autopublish package removed from my application. When I run `Photos.find().count();` from the browser or `db.Photos.find().count();` from the command line they both show a count of 0.

Comment: Also, that data from Facebook listed above is invalid JSON (no closing array ). Is that just a typo here, or are you trying to insert invalid results?

Comment: If you put a callback in Photos.insert, does it give an error?

Comment: Yes that was just a typo in the JSON--good catch. I just tried to render a callback in Photos.insert, however nothing came back. Also, just to check that I'm doing the callback correctly, I added `Photos.insert(data, function(error, result){
            console.log(error);
            });`. Does that look correct?

Comment: Yeah, that should do it.

Comment: hmmm, nothing from the callback. I just posted my code on github (link above). Hopefully that might help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figured got it to work. Many thanks to Dave and emgee for your help! Below is the code for those who are having the same issue. Also, please let me know if there is a better way to go about this.

Server code:

```
function Facebook(accessToken) {
    this.fb = Meteor.require('fbgraph');
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
    this.fb.setAccessToken(this.accessToken);
    this.options = {
        timeout: 3000,
        pool: {maxSockets: Infinity},
        headers: {connection: "keep-alive"}
    }
    this.fb.setOptions(this.options);
}

Facebook.prototype.query = function(query, method) {
    var self = this;
    var method = (typeof method === 'undefined') ? 'get' : method;
    var data = Meteor.sync(function(done) {
        self.fb[method](query, function(err, res) {
            done(null, res);
        });
    });
    return data.result;
}

Facebook.prototype.getUserData = function() {
    return this.query('me/photos');
}

Meteor.methods({
    getUserData: function() {
        var fb = new Facebook(Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken);
        var data = fb.getUserData();
        _.forEach(data.data, function(photo) {
            Photos.insert(photo, function(err) { 
                if(err) console.error(err); 
            });
        });
    }
});

Meteor.publish('picture', function() {
  return Photos.find();
});
```

Collections:

```
Photos = new Meteor.Collection('picture');
```

Client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('picture');

Template.facebookphoto.helpers({
        pictures: function () {
             return Photos.find();
          }     
});

Template.fbgraph.events({
    'click #btn-user-data': function(e) {
        Meteor.call('getUserData', function(err, data) {
             $('#result').text(EJSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4));
         });
    }
});
```

HTML Templates:

```
<template name="fbgraph">
    <div id="main" class="row-fluid">
      {{> facebookphoto}}
    </div>

    <button class="btn" id="btn-user-data">Get User Data</button>
    <div class="well">
        <pre id="result"></pre>
    </div>
</template>


<template name="facebookphoto">
  <div class="photos">
    {{#each pictures}}
      {{> photoItem}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="photoItem">
  <div class="photo">
    <div class="photo-content">
      <a href="{{source}}">
       <img class="img-rounded" src="{{picture}}">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Have you defined the Photos as a Meteor collection?
- Inserting the data as-is might work, but I think what you really want to do is insert each photo one at a time into the collection. Something like this:

  ```
  _.forEach(data.data, function(photo) {
      Photos.insert(photo, function(err) { if(err) console.error(err); });
  }
  ```
- If this still doesn't work, try making sure you're getting the data from Facebook just before you insert it.

Comment: I've defined Photos in Meteor collections as `Photos = new Meteor.Collection('picture');`. I believe that is all that is needed in collections, but let me know if I'm wrong. I made the changes you suggested to insert each photo, however it still isn't pulling for some reason. Finally, when I run `db.users.find().pretty()` it returns my user information, so it the FB API appears to be working. I'm going to set up a github repo and edit the question a bit to see if that will help bring some clarity to my question. Thanks!

Comment: It looks good to me. Do you get an error when the insert is performed? Try putting console.log(data) before the forEach, and also inside the _.forEach to see if the data is definitely being iterated over and insert is being called.

Comment: Interesting. I just noticed that MongoDB is receiving the data, however it is storing it as pictures, not Photos. If I run `db.picture.find().count();` I receive 160 photos, but if I run `db.Photos.find().count();` I receive 0. Looks like I defined it wrong somewhere...

Comment: Excellent. Just got it working by turning on auto-publish. Now it is just an issue with setting up the publish/subscription.